# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent calculated by sql field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how I can append atribute in model, that calculated by sql?

I have try this:

```
protected $appends = ['comment_qty'];
public function getCommentQtyAttribute()
{
    return DB::raw("(select 1) as comment_qty");
}
```

It's not working

Answer (score 0):

Define a mutator method `setCommentQtyAttribute` on your model, where `comment_qty` is your custom column name.

Look at the below...

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'comments';
    protected $appends = array('comment_qty');

    public function setCommentQtyAttribute()
    {
        return DB::raw("(select 1) as field");
    }
}
```

For  more information : [Accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: Nothing hapens, field is empty

Comment: Is comment_qty column appends? if yes, Then the problem was code inside `setCommentQtyAttribute()` method.

Comment: Yes, it's appended. But what wrong in DB::raw("(select 1)"); in mysql DB?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve inside `setCommentQtyAttribute()` ?

Comment: I try to append count of comments to each row in one query, like
select t.*, (select count() from comments c where c.task_id = t.id) as comment_qty from task t

Comment: I did like this...
$tasks = Task::with('status')
            ->select()
            ->addSelect([DB::raw('(select 1) as comment_qty')])
            ->get()
            ->sortBy('id');

Comment: Later, i will try work with scope and model query builder

Answer (score 0):

Another yet solution, add to model.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    static::addGlobalScope('any', function (Builder $builder) {
       $builder->select(['*', DB::raw("'any' as any")]);
    });
}
```